# how to convert HTML file to UTF-8 using Perl

Tags: perl, firefox, encoding, utf-8, meta-tags

I have an HTML file in the below location

> http://jmp.sh/WnRlO82

I want to convert the above HTML file to UTF-8 encoding format,
I tried the following way in Perl

```
use strict;
use Cwd;
use HTML::Entities;
use HTML::Entities::Numbered;
use HTML::Strip;
use Encode;
use utf8;

my $parentPath = $ARGV[0];
#my $parentPath = getcwd()."/".$epubHTMLName;
opendir(FOLDER,$parentPath) || die "No such directory !";
my @readDir = readdir(FOLDER);
close FOLDER;

foreach(@readDir){
    #print $_."\n";
    my $fold = $_;
    my $match = lc($fold);
    my @dotcount;
    while ($match=~m/(html)/gi){
        push(@dotcount,$1);
    }
    my $totalcount = @dotcount+0;

    print $fold."\n";

    if ($fold ne "." && $fold ne ".." && $totalcount eq 1) {
        my $input = $parentPath."\\".$fold;
        my $output = getcwd()."/Output/".$fold;
        open(HTMLFILE, $input) || die "Check your File !";
        local $/ = undef;
        my $htmlcontent = <HTMLFILE>;
        $htmlcontent = decode_entities($htmlcontent);
        $htmlcontent =~s/\x{feff}//g;
        close HTMLFILE;

        open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $output;
        print {$out} $htmlcontent;
        close $out;
    }
}
```

After I convert by the above method I can see in UTF-8 format in `Google Chrome` but i can not see it in `FireFox`. So Need a way to see the HTML file in UTF-8 in both `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

Output file for your reference:   http://jmp.sh/tp5QHwG

Comment: Kindly view it in both Chrome and Firefox and see the difference

Comment: Your output is most definitely UTF-8. If the problem is that Firefox doesn't see that, just give it `<meta charset='utf-8'/>`.

Comment: Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"/>` to the header.

Comment: Thanks You So much for your support and Answer It works well and good thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output file is correct.

Firefox doesn't show page in UTF-8 encoding by default. [See this discussion](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/987964).

Just add the below in `<head>` section to tell it explicitly.

`<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Comment: It's xhtml, so you have to close the tag.